# How to disable direct access to jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page in java project, and i use from below code for hidden jsp extension from url, but also load my page with jsp extension in url. how to prevent of this?
my code:

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>myTest</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/testing.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myTest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and url testing is : localhost/testing.jsp  and my testing page is access.

Answer (score 5):

For a quick solution, just put your JSP pages to the `WEB-INF` folder (then they will not be directly accessible) and define them like this:

```
   <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>hidden</display-name>
        <servlet-name>hidden</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/hidden.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hidden</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hidden</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but you should consider using frameworks to do it, like Struts2 or Spring.

Comment: @Digicom For the solution I've provided, you don't need any framework. Framework is just advice for the future to consider.

Comment: I've seen multiple answers suggest this, but it doesn't work at all for me. Including "WEB-INF" in the URL still allows for direct access of the JSP.

Comment: @Reinderien what server/web container are you using? Most servers protect WEB-INF by default, so I'm pretty surprised by behavior you are describing.

Comment: @Gas Jetty 9. Very strange to me. I ended up adding a security restriction to web.xml, which did the trick.

Comment: @Reinderien that looks like bug in the Jetty, that directory shouldnt be publicly available by the spec, so you should report that issue in Jetty forums. From Jetty docs: `/WEB-INF/-    Special Servlet API defined directory used to store anything related to the Web Application that are not part of the public access of the Web Application. If there is content that is accessed by a Web Application internally, but that should also never be accessed directly by a web browser, this is the directory it would placed in.`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a filter and deny access to jsps.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>JspFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>my.JspFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>JspFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Fitler:

```
public class JspFilter implements Filter{
  public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletReponse response,                
           FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletRequest req= (HttpServletRequest) request;
    req.getRequestDispather("error.jsp).forward(request,response);
  }
}
```

Comment: From testing, this causes an infinite loop error because dispatch error.jsp will be captured by the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I would map the url to the servlet and then return the jsp from the servlet. eg:

In web xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourpackage.testServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In servlet:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("testing.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

So your url pattern will be /test but the testing.jsp page will be loaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but on this way for every jsp page will be a servlet, right? there is no other way?

Comment: Yes it might do. But potentially you can map more than one URL to the same servlet and then use he request url to determine which jsp to return. I personally use the Spring MVC framework to do what you're trying to do and it's made a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent direct access to jsp files by adding the following to your web.xml, altering the url pattern as required.

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>JSP Files</web-resource-name>
            <description>No direct access to JSP files</description>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>No direct browser access to JSP files</description>
            <role-name>NobodyHasThisRole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Comment: this restricts all request even i can't access the login page which is like /pages/login.jps